# How do I give a control the focus on a form that is not displaying?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, unit-testing

This may sound a little odd, but I need in a unit test to give a specific control on a Windows Forms screen that isn't actually being displayed, the focus. This is because the form is being used as an 'engine' by programmatically clicking on buttons on it and reading the results from properties. That's the given, and my job is to test that when a button is 'clicked',  after the button has completed its action the focus is returned to another control.

My problem is how to set the focus on a specific control, which doesn't seem to work (eg executing `form.myControl.Select()` or `form.myControl.Focus()` ). I'm told that this is because the form isn't currently being displayed, but that's only speculation.

Can anyone tell me how to do this in a unit test environment?

Comment: You simply can't set the focus to a non-visible window. By definition, the control with the focus will be the one that receives keyboard input; an invisible control cannot receive keyboard input.

Comment: Can you suggest how I might programmatically test that after a button on this form is clicked, the focus returns to the control that had it before the button was clicked? That is the functionality I must prove. I can't actually display the form because the test server runs 'blind' and does not have access to the display.

Comment: Clearly you'll need to fix that test server problem, you can't test UI code without creating the UI first.